# WPF BindingSource

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

Working on learning WPF by converting one of my applications over from WinForms
What is the WPF way of doing the following

```
 DataTable _current = _connections.Copy();
 BindingSource _bs = new BindingSource();
 bs.DataSource = _current;
 bs.Filter = "Client = '" + _selectedClient + "'";
```

After the new DataTable table is filtered down, then I would need to assign the binding source to a DataGrid.

***Update 2***
I have added the following

```
 public ObservableCollection<SupportConnectionData> _supportConnections = new ObservableCollection<SupportConnectionData>();
```

turn the datatable given into ObservableCollection

```
 DataTable _dt = Global.RequestSupportConnections(_token);
                _dt = Crypto.DecryptDataTable(_dt);
                ObservableCollection<SupportConnectionData> _connections = new ObservableCollection<SupportConnectionData>();

                foreach (DataRow _row in _dt.Rows)
                {
                    SupportConnectionData _supportConnection = new SupportConnectionData()
                    {
                        _client = _row["Client"].ToString(),
                        _server = _row["Server"].ToString(),
                        _user = _row["User"].ToString(),
                        _connected = _row["Connected"].ToString(),
                        _disconnected = _row["Disconnected"].ToString(),
                        _reason = _row["Reason"].ToString(),
                        _caseNumber = _row["CaseNumber"].ToString()
                    };
                    _connections.Add(_supportConnection);
                }

                //let me assign new collection to bound collection
                App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { _supportConnections = _connections; }));
                //this allows it to update changes to ui
                dgSupportConnections.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { dgSupportConnections.DataContext = _supportConnections; }));
```

XAML

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="dgSupportConnections" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client" Binding="{Binding _client}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Server" Binding="{Binding _server}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="User" Binding="{Binding _user}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Connected" Binding="{Binding _connected}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Disconnected" Binding="{Binding _disconnected}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reason" Binding="{Binding _reason}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Case Number" Binding="{Binding _caseNumber}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 5):

get your database objects (or however you get them) into a collection (say MyCollection as ObservableCollection of *Type*) or collection view source then bind to that.  IN wpf you have to work with the context of the class that the xaml view is bound to.  So if the immediate context of the datagrid is the code behind then you would add this line to the datagrid to bind to the collection:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" / >
```

In win forms you can assign the collections to the datagirid in code, but in WPF you declare the binding in the xaml and the "WPF engine" takes care of the rest.  There is a bit of a learning curve but it is really flexible and in my opinion reduces code.

But this raises a larger discussion about the architecture of your application.  I would suggest looking at MVVM to create a decoupling or separation of concerns between the model (your data), the view (user interface), and the ViewModel (which handles your business logic).  THis will make you application more maintainable and testable.

**EDIT 1:  EXAMPLE**

xaml of the window:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectCollection}" DataContext="{Binding}"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind of the Xaml window:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

class MainWindow
{


    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjectCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        // This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            MyObject newObject = new MyObject {
                age = i,
                name = "Full Name"
            };
            MyObjectCollection.Add(newObject);
        }


        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = MyObjectCollection;
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

While this example works for learning, I DO NOT suggest this method for production apps.  I think you need to look into MVVM, or MVC in order to have an application that is maintainable and testable.

Comment: yep, basically covers it :)

Comment: Updated original post with what I'm trying

Comment: can you post the datacontext of your window/page or whatever is holding your datagrid

Comment: updated with full xaml of the control. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: is the tab item the top level object in the page?  how do you define your code behind?  when you run the app is there any binding errors in the output window.  THis can help track down what is happening

Comment: okay, you can assign the datacontex in code, but that defeats the benefits of wpf.  You don't have to do that.  Again, what is the full xaml of your page/control or whatever the datagrid resides in.  Did you get any erros in your output window?

Comment: I included a simple example in EDIT 1